# Macro expansion and href with hyperlink

Tags: macros, hyperref, expansion

I have  very simple question I hope! I am writing a book on MPASM (PIC) assembler and there will be very many similar links to programs, hex files, videos etc. These will be enclosed in a standard `tabular`, which will be used many times. The `tabular` works fine when I type in the links directly within the `tabular`, but inside a macro the only one which works is the  `\href{{#1}}`. This I think is fully expanded as the URL is passed to the macro directly. The others such as `\href{http://stbarnabaschapel.net/hex/PROJ{#2}.hex}` do not work as the `#2` which will be something like `0x00` I think does not get expanded properly. I am hoping there is a simple way around this.

```
\newcommand{\linktable}[3]{

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cellcolor{red}{\href{{#1}}{\color{white}Video {\large \eye}}}&\cellcolor{orange}
\href{http://stbarnabaschapel.net/hex/PROJ{#2}.hex}{Hex File {\Hexasteel}}&
\cellcolor{yellow} \href{http://stbarnabaschapel.net/asm/proj{#2}.asm}
{Listing {\rightpointleft}} &\cellcolor{green}\href{http://stbarnabaschapel.net 
/package/PROJ{#2}.zip}{Project  {\satellitedish}}&\cellcolor{blue}
\href{http://stbarnabaschapel.net/dfiles/d16F1847_{#3}.inc}{{\color{white}'d' file {\smallpencil}}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: Omit the curly braces around `#1`, `#2`, ...

Example:

```
\href{http://stbarnabaschapel.net/asm/proj{#2}.asm}
```

If `#2` is `foobar`, then it expands to:

```
\href{http://stbarnabaschapel.net/asm/proj{foobar}.asm}
```

The curly braces are *not* going away, because they are not parsed
as argument. Thus the curly braces become part of the URL.

Also `\href{{#1}}` is wrong in the same way. It is possible, that the implementation strips another set of braces, but this is accidental and it cannot be relied on.

PS: A comment character is needed after:

```
\newcommand{\linktable}[3]{
```

to remove the line end:

```
\newcommand{\linktable}[3]{%
```

Otherwise there can be an unwanted line space:

```
Some text of the previous paragraph.
\linktable...
```

The empty line in `\linktable` ends the previous paragraph. TeX removes *one*
white space at the end of a paragraph (using `\unskip`). Usually it would be the line end of the last line of the paragraph. But if `\linktable` inserts another space, then this space is removed and the previous is kept. Depending on the line breaking it can result in an extra empty line with an underfull `\hbox` warning.

Comment: Yes that does work. Had the \href{{#1}} also not worked it would have set me on the right track. The question is now answered